# underscore groupBy inner key

Tags: underscore.js

I am trying to `_.groupBy` using a key inside one object of my collection.

Example: 
Given the following collection:

```
[
  { _id: 1234, data: { label: '1' } },
  { _id: 2345, data: { label: '1' } },
  { _id: 3456, data: { label: '1' } },
  { _id: 4567, data: { label: '2' } }
]
```

Grouping by first level key like `_id` gives me the following result: `{1234: Array(1), 2345: Array(1), 3456: Array(1), 4567: Array(1)}`, which is correct.

Is it possible to group by a key not in the first level like `label`?
I am doing the following: `_.groupBy(A, 'data.label')` but the result is `{undefined: Array(4)}` and I would like to have `{1: Array(3), 2: Array(1)}`.

PS: I can not normalize my data, the structure is as it is.

Thank you.

Comment: groupBy can take a function as well: `_.groupBy(data, item => item.label);`

Comment: Nice one! But in my use case would be `_.groupBy(data, item => item.data.label);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter/Best answer: `_.groupBy(data, item => item.data.label);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this without underscore. You define your own getter for a path and then group by the value. Hope this helps.

```js
const data = [
    { _id: 1234, data: { label: '1' } },
    { _id: 2345, data: { label: '1' } },
    { _id: 3456, data: { label: '1' } },
    { _id: 4567, data: { label: '2' } }
];

const get = (o, path) => path.split('.').reduce((acc, key) => acc[key], o);

const groupBy = (data, path) =>
    
    data.reduce((acc, val) => {
        
        const groupKey = get(val, path);
        
        acc[groupKey] = (acc[groupKey] || []).concat(val);
        
        return acc;
    }, {});

console.log(groupBy(data, 'data.label'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Working as expected!